# Batch : ECHO outputs chinese character instead of numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, character-encoding, cjk

I'm trying to work around some logs to extract the data I want and to push it into another simplified `.txt` file (before going for the next step).

Here's the bit of code I've been trying to use to reach my goal:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

for %%i in (C:\Test_Analyse\*files*.txt) do (
SET va=%%i
SET va=!va:~16,-31!
find /v /c "" %%i | FINDSTR /V /R /C:"^$">>C:\test_results\!va!log3.txt
set /p var=<C:\test_results\!va!log3.txt
set var=!var:~68,10!
echo !var!>>C:\test_results\!va!log2.txt
)

endlocal
```

The `C:\test_results\!va!log3.txt` file content is : `---------- C:\TEST_ANALYSE\1K43782_TEST_RENAMED_FILES_20210915.TXT: 223856`.

As far as I know, it does its job except for the `echo !var!>>C:\test_results\!va!log2.txt` part. It prints Chinese characters in my output file instead of `223856`. On a side note, when I discard the `@echo OFF`, I notice the `ECHO` line working properly in CMD - so I guess it's maybe about encryption? But I tried a few things around that, without success sadly.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to first of all change directory to your target, instead of tring to remove its path as a substring later? i.e. 1. `@CD /D "C:\Test_Analyse"`, then you could directly retrieve the output you require within the outer `for` loop. 2. `@For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V /C "" *files*.txt') Do @Echo %%H`.

Comment: It sounds like your input files are encoded in UTF-16. Try encoding them in ANSI or UTF-8 if you can.

Comment: @Compo It never occured to me i could go this way to shorten the code and make it more simple. Thanks! My problem still happened with these lines though, but i understood the issue when i read SomethingDark comment.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks! I was going the other way around, trying to change my .bat encoding. When i manually changed the output file encoding, i had better results but still some things to polish. Finally, i'm kinda at fault here, i linked half my .bat in my question, and the problem lies in the missing first part : i call a .ps1 for a Get-Content | replace and i was using the >>output, instead of Out-File, which seems to go for UTF-16 by default... Sorry & Thanks! ^^

Comment: The `Out-File` command can specify an `-Encoding` parameter. Use `help Out-File -Full` to read all about it.

Comment: @lit That's what i did to get over the UTF-16 default encoding of >> Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in comments.